# How to only change toggle image of child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plus/minus image toggle using jquery, but when I click on the `ul`, every plus/minus image changes at the same time. I need it to only change the image for the ul it was clicked on.

**jQuery:**

```
$("#xmlDiv").on("click", "ul", function(e) {
    $(this).find(".mainlist").slideToggle('slow', function () {
        if($('span.minus img').attr('src') == 'images/plus.png')
            $('span.minus img').attr('src', "images/minus.png");
        else
            $('span.minus img').attr('src', "images/plus.png");
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="xmlDiv">
    <ul class="section">
        <li class="root"><span class="minus"><img src="images/minus.png"></span> Antivirus Compliance
            <ul class="mainlist" style="margin-left: -25px; display: block;">
                <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span> <span class="desc_span" tooltip="Antivirus is not installed.">Not Installed</span>
                </li>
                <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span> <span class="desc_span" tooltip="Antivirus is not running.">Not Running</span>
                </li>
                <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span> <span class="desc_span" tooltip="Antivirus is not updated.">Not Updated</span>
                </li>
                <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span> <span class="desc_span" tooltip="">Non Compliant</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="section">
        <li class="root"><span class="minus"><img src="images/minus.png"></span> Classification
            <ul class="mainlist" style="margin-left:-25px;">
                <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span> <span class="desc_span" tooltip="">Classification</span>
                </li>
                <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span> <span class="desc_span" tooltip="">DHCP</span>
                </li>
                <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span> <span class="desc_span" tooltip="">p0f</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting the `span.minus img` for all `ul` elements. What you need to do is use `$(this)` to grab only the spans relative to the clicked `ul`

```js
$("#xmlDiv").on("click", "ul", function(e) {
    var clickedUl = $(this);                                      // reference to the clicked ul element
    clickedUl.find(".mainlist").slideToggle('slow', function () { // toggle the .mainlist class element within the clicked ul element
        clickedUl.find('span.minus img');                         // find the img within the clicked ul
        if(img.attr('src') === 'images/plus.png')
            img.attr('src', "images/minus.png");
        else
            img.attr('src', "images/plus.png");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="xmlDiv">
    <ul class="section">
        <li class="root"><span class="minus"><img src="images/minus.png"></span> Antivirus Compliance
            <ul class="mainlist" style="margin-left: -25px; display: block;">
                <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span> <span class="desc_span" tooltip="Antivirus is not installed.">Not Installed</span>
                </li>
                <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span> <span class="desc_span" tooltip="Antivirus is not running.">Not Running</span>
                </li>
                <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span> <span class="desc_span" tooltip="Antivirus is not updated.">Not Updated</span>
                </li>
                <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span> <span class="desc_span" tooltip="">Non Compliant</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="section">
        <li class="root"><span class="minus"><img src="images/minus.png"></span> Classification
            <ul class="mainlist" style="margin-left:-25px;">
                <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span> <span class="desc_span" tooltip="">Classification</span>
                </li>
                <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span> <span class="desc_span" tooltip="">DHCP</span>
                </li>
                <li class="desc"> <span style="color:#e4e4e4;">-</span> <span class="desc_span" tooltip="">p0f</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` of first `ul`

```
$("#xmlDiv").on("click", "ul", function(e) {
    var firstThis=$(this);
    $(this).find(".mainlist").slideToggle('slow', function () {

        if(firstThis.find('span.minus img').attr('src') == 'images/plus.png')
            firstThis.find('span.minus img').attr('src', "images/minus.png");
        else
            firstThis.find('span.minus img').attr('src', "images/plus.png");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lTasty/9pohn7e0/